# Importing a topology from a text file in INET

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I want to create a topology from a  .txt file on my deskop. I used the "import topology from a text file" in INET but its just giving me an error "error, file not found".

Comment: Your question is missing the most basic indicator that it actually *is* a question: the question mark. It's completely unclear what you expect here. We cannot help you without any information.

Comment: Did you try to specify a full filepath? Does your program run in the Desktop directory?